# How to return multiple lists with a single get request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to write a **GET** request for my Django app to get three lists. I want to apply a filter to my database and **return them in different lists in one response**. These are the three lists that I want, and I want to filter them with `{"to do," "in progress," "Done"}`.

Is there a way to return multiple lists in one response? Or must I write different APIs for every one of them?

[image]

This is my `views.py`:

```
class AllCardstView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = Card_Serializer.CardAssigneeSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk=None):

        req_check = have_queryparams(request, 'team_pk')

        if not req_check.have_all:
            return Response({'error': req_check.error_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        team_pk = request.query_params.get("team_pk")

        cradlistDone = Card.objects.filter(team=team_pk).filter(status="Done")
        cradlistInProgress = Card.objects.filter(team=team_pk).filter(status="In progress")
        cradlistToDo = Card.objects.filter(team=team_pk).filter(status="TO DO")
        workspace_cards={}
        workspace_cards['ToDO'] = Card_Serializer.CardAssigneeSerializer(cradlistToDo, many=True)
        workspace_cards['InProgress'] = Card_Serializer.CardAssigneeSerializer(cradlistInProgress, many=True)
        workspace_cards['Done'] = Card_Serializer.CardAssigneeSerializer(cradlistDone, many=True)
        serializer=workspace_cards
        return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But I got this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
 raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ListSerializer is not JSON serializable
[15/May/2021 16:53:31] "GET /api/v1/postideas/all_card/?team_pk=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 120731
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't know is there a way to return multiple lists in one response? or I should write different APIs for every one of them.

Comment: It's up to you, your endpoints can return whatever you like. Maybe it's one endpoint that returns a response containing separate lists, maybe it returns one list that's split up by the client, maybe it's separate endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to write a restful API, a GET HTTP request to resource URL should return the list of resources.

Let's say your resource is Task which is represented like below in models.py

in your app/models.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices

```
class Task(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=[
           ('todo', 'To Do'), 
           ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
           ('done', 'Done')
        ]
    )
```

in your app/serializers.py https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```

in your app/views.py https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

```
class TaskViewset(serializers.ModelViewset):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

in your app/urls.py https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'task', TaskViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path("v1/", include(router.urls))
]
```

After that, when the client makes an HTTP get request to '/v1/task/' all the tasks would be returned.

If you'd like to get tasks by their status you can set up [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html) and configure your viewset. Then you'd be able to filter the tasks by their status with an HTTP get request to */v1/task/?status='in_progress*

Comment: Thank you so much! I have updated my question. Would you please recheck it?

Comment: You should fix your last line in get method like below.

return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

(simply change serializer to serializer.data)

Comment: I tried this but i got this error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data' "